# Can separate access modifiers be specified for the get and set accessors of a property?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, access-modifiers

Can we specify the access modifiers for the get and set accessors of property in C#/.NET?

If so, what would be the best approach to implement this?

Comment: What documentation/resources have you already looked at?

Comment: Yes you can, but they cannot go more accessible than the modifier given to the property itself, and the property must feature both get and set.

Comment: *implement this one*? Please post the remainder of your assignment.

Comment: @Daniel: You really want to do the rest of his assignment for him, too?

Comment: @Cody Gray: I wrapped my comment in <sarcastic> </sarcastic>, but it forgot that this doesn't show up in comments.

Comment: @All Though it sounds very much like homework, the question is fairly well defined.  All that has been exhibited here is a lack of search skills and a lack of understanding about how "implementing" a property is simply coding it so it compiles.  Surely down-votes and sarcastic comments are less helpful than correctly tagging it as homework, which at best would be a guess.

Comment: @Adam: Did u mean that a property must have both get and set accessors.

Comment: @Sukhi, for you to modify one of them to be different from the main property - yes, or so my compiler is telling me.  Cody Gray has answered your question with a good sample.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It is called Asymmetric Accessor Accessibility, and you can read the MSDN documentation for it [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx). The code would look something like this:

```
public int Age
{
    get
    {
        return _age;
    }
    protected set
    {
        _age = value;
    }
}
```

However, there are a couple of important caveats to keep in mind:

- Only one accessor can be modified.
- Any restrictions placed on an individual accessor must be *more* restrictive than the accessibility level of the property itself, not less.
- You cannot use accessor modifiers on an interface or an explicit implementation of an interface member.

Comment: +another caveat, both get and set must be specified to declare a different modifier on the get or set.

Comment: @Adam: Well that just kind of makes sense... Why would you ever need to declare a *different* modifier on something if you only have one of those things in the first place?

Comment: exactly, but based on the types of responses being given to the OP, I added is as distinct clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can...

```
public class Example
{
    public string Property
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Property2
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: -1 : Only any one accesssor can have the modifier. In addition, the get or set cannot have a "public" access modifier.

Comment: @Sandeep - Amended. you can now remove your -1. The code above builds fine

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx shows the possible modifiers. If you want to have different modifiers, write:

```
[Modifier] [DataType] ProperyName{
    [Modifier] get{}
    [Modifier] set{}
}
```

However if you declare inner modifiers, they must be less or equal visible than the outer ones.